# Access vue-i18n messages as object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I want to create a dynamical slider which depends on the page.

```
    security_signin: {
        slide1: 'Kitten1',
        slide2: 'Kitten2',
    },
    signup: {
        slide1: 'Kitten1',
        slide2: 'Kitten2',
        slide3: 'Kitten3'
    }
```

The thing is I want to render in my component my slider in function of the number of slide.

So this is something like this:

```
<slide v-for="(item, index) in $t('message.'+page).length">
    <p v-html="$t('message.'+page+'.slide'+index)"></p>
</slide>
```

However I do not manage to access properly messages this way.
Since  `$t('message.'+page).length` is giving me back the length of the first slide (7 in the Kitten1 case).

Is there a way to access i18n without recreating an instance of it ?

Comment: could you provide more code? data object and methods

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim what methods do you want ? 
`$t()` is a native i18n function standing for `translation()` the rest is basicaly just a vue component (vue-slider).

Comment: so what about your data object?

Comment: please reply i'm waiting

Comment: This is not a data object this just the 'message object' your sending to i18n youre only missing the wrapper : `messages: { }`

Comment: so you want to get the length of `security_signin` and `signup`

Comment: Yes indeed sir !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180115/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-baldrani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so it appears that `$t()` is always returning a string.

So the solution I found out was to import messages in my components and directly use it from there :

```
import messages from '../messages'

export default {
   props: ['page', 'locale'],
   data(){
       return {
           slides: messages[this.locale].message[this.page]
       }
   }
}

<slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides">
    <p v-html="slide"></p>
    <img :src="'/assets/img/slider-bg-'+ i +'.png'" alt="">
</slide>
```

Answer (score 13):

It's very simple, access the messages [property](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#messages-2) from `$i18n`. For instance:

```
<slide v-for="(item, index) in Object.keys($i18n.messages[$i18n.fallbackLocale].message[page]).length">
    <p v-html="$t('message.'+page+'.slide'+index)"></p>
</slide>
```

In more detail, `$i18n.messages` holds all your translations, e.g.

```
en: {
    security_signin: {
        slide1: 'Kitten1',
        slide2: 'Kitten2',
    },
    signup: {
        slide1: 'Kitten1',
        slide2: 'Kitten2',
        slide3: 'Kitten3'
    }
}
```

Subset a locale of your choice, `$i18n.fallbackLocale` for the fallback locale or `$i18n.locale` for your current locale. You should obtain your javascript object.

Be very careful, when you translate with `$t()` any missing translations are recovered from the fallback locale. But when you access the javascript object directly, you give up this safety net. Some locales may have missing keys.

In this case `fallbackLocale` suffices because we don't want to access the translations, only the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are using objects instead of arrays but JavaScript objects do not have a `length` property - you can try with arrays:

```
// English locale
{
  "message":
  {
    security_signing:
    {
      slides:
      [
        'Kitten1',
        'Kitten2'
      ]
    },
    signup:
    {
      slides:
      [
        'Kitten1',
        'Kitten2',
        'Kitten3'
      ]
    }
  }
}

<slide v-for="item in $t('message.'+page+'.slides').length">
    <p v-html="item"></p>
</slide>
```

Comment: I sadly don't think this is working. Morevor I don't know how to check inside my component but when I try to display this: `{{ Object.keys($t('message.'+page)).length }}` I have the same result as `{{ $t('message.'+page).length }}`

Comment: Updated my answer to use arrays instead of objects

Answer (score 0):

in Vue 3 version

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import pluralRules from "./rules/pluralization";
import numberFormats from "./rules/numbers.js";
import datetimeFormats from "./rules/datetime.js";
import en from "./locales/en.json";
import tr from "./locales/tr.json";

export default createI18n({
  locale: import.meta.env.VITE_DEFAULT_LOCALE,
  fallbackLocale: import.meta.env.VITE_FALLBACK_LOCALE,
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: { tr, en },
  runtimeOnly: false,
  pluralRules,
  numberFormats,
  datetimeFormats,
});
```

After the definitions you can get your messages from global object.

```
let locale = this.i18n.global.locale.value
let messages = this.i18n.global.messages.value[locale]
```