# How to access an object from vue-18n in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I am trying to access an object from vi18n

Vue: **3.2.0**

Vite: **4.2.0**

vue-18n: **9.2.2**

**i18n.js**

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from "./locales/en.js"

 // Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'en', // set locale
    legacy: false,
    messages: { en } // set locale messages
})

export default i18n
```

**en.js**

```
export const en = {
    parent: {
       child1: 'a',
       child2: 'b'
    }
}
```

In the component i am access `this.$t('parent')` to access all childs but it actually returning the `parent` as a string itself. And it shows a warning **[intlify] Not found 'parent' key in 'en' locale messages**

But if i am accessing like this `this.$t('parent.child1')` it is able to get the value of child1.

In older version vue 2 and vue-18n. it used to return the complete object.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This could be XY problem. I don't think that this.$t('parent') is documented usage

Comment: So here i want to loop through parent and display the options as 'a' and 'b'. If i loop the parent object it is easy to display all the values inside it. Otherwise i have to manually pluck each child `$t('parent.child1)`, `$t('parent.child2')` ... `$t{'parent.child100'}`. Note it used to work in vuei18n version 8.x with vue 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344776/access-vue-i18n-messages-as-object

Comment: Not a good idea at all to rely on it for app logic. t() is for translation, if it worked differently, it was a quirk. If the keys fully duplicate messages object then get it and iterate it. In composition api it's useI18n().messages for current locale, I suppose. Or import en.js directly where you use it, since some locales could miss some keys, that's one of the problems with this approach